# How to serve css using oak?

Tags: javascript, deno

I'm using Deno

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
const port = 3000;
const app = new Application();
//HTML
app.use(async (ctx,next)=>{
  await ctx.send({
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/views`,
    index: "index.html",
  })
  next()
})
// static content
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  const root = `${Deno.cwd()}/static`
  try {
      await context.send({ root })
  } catch {
      next()
  }
})

await app.listen({port});
```

My folder has the following structure.

```
Landing
| Routes
| -- index.js
| static (all JavaScript files for frontend, css, images)
| --main.css
| --main.js
| --images
| views
| --index.html
|
```

Here is what I have inside my index.js file. I am getting **net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: How are you calling the route? Also, please tell the contents of `static` folder

Comment: You may find [this example](https://github.com/thecodeholic/deno-serve-static-files) helpful.

Comment: The example @Nur pointed out didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a minimal example that worked for me with Deno 1.8.

I used a `Router` in Oak, because I'm not sure how to do this with just an application. The key is the following lines:

```js
router.get('/static/:path+', async (ctx) => {
  await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
    root: Deno.cwd(),
  });
});
```

Where `router.get('/static/:path+', ...)` calls the callback for any path that starts with `/static/`. If you're not familiar with the `:path+` syntax, the colon makes the part of the request a parameter accessible through `ctx.params.path` and I believe that the `+` includes the following parts of the URL. This is important for matching the request to the intended route.

The string for `path` would be available in `ctx.params.path`, but it may or may not exist. I found it easier to just get the whole from the get request available in `ctx.request.url.pathname`, which always exists. Similar to what you were doing, the file at that path is then sent by the router when it is asked for.

### Full example

```js
// app.ts

import { Application, Router, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const port = 3000;

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

// HTML
router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
  const body = await Deno.readTextFile(Deno.cwd() + '/views/index.html')
  ctx.response.body = body;
});

// Static content
router.get('/static/:path+', async (ctx) => {
  await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
    root: Deno.cwd(),
  });
});

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({port});
```

```html
<!-- views/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hi there</h1>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* static/style.css */
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@audrow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938017/16219352), here's a more "secure" way of doing it.

```
const main = new Router();

main.get('/static/:path+', async (ctx: Context) => {
    return await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
        root: join(Deno.cwd(), 'public')
    });
});
```

Put your static files under the `public/static` directory and access it from `/static/your_file.extension`
Under the `public` directory, you can also add a `views` directory and place your HTML/HTM files.

Pointing the `root` to your `CWD` is quite dangerous even though Deno is secure. In this approach, you point the `root` to your `${Deno.cwd()}/public` folder. Also, you're gonna need the `join` function from `https://deno.land/std@0.97.0/path/mod.ts`.

Full code example:

```
// mod.ts
export * from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v7.5.0/mod.ts';
export * from 'https://deno.land/std@0.97.0/path/mod.ts';
```

```
// index.ts
import { Application, Context, join, Router, send } from './mod.ts';

const app = new Application();
const main = new Router();

main.get('/static/:path+', async (ctx: Context) => {
    return await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
        root: join(Deno.cwd(), 'public')
    });
});

main.get('/', ({ response }: Context) => {
    response.body = 'hello world'
});

app.use(main.routes())
app.use(main.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

EDIT:
Here's how your working directory should look like

```
- app       # Your app
 - public   # The public folder
  - views   # HTML
  - static  # CSS and JS
```